# 4D (or higher) popular vtk or netCDF dataset

Tags: visualization, vtk, netcdf, paraview, datavisualization.toolkit

I am looking for a 4 dimensional(or higher dimension) popular dataset for my term project in Scientific visualization. I searched on the Internet and found 3D only. Any idea

Comment: By 4D you mean time transient data?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for something small, the latest versions of ParaView come with a data set named can.ex2 (look in the Examples directory). For somewhat larger data you can download some examples from https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/files.html. The file tos_O1_2001-2002.nc is technically a 2D time series, but ParaView can load it up as a sphere in 3D. The file rhum.2003.nc is a true 3D time series. Both of these files are loaded as "NetCDF files generic and CF conventions".

Comment: Thank you so much I will look at it. I found this website useful: https://ecowatch.ncddc.noaa.gov/erddap/griddap/NCOM_Region1_3D_agg.html